# Should I require a module in every file or require it once and pass it as argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lets say I have 50 modules and each needs Underscore library. Is it better to load Underscore like that 50 times:

```
//a module
var _ = require('underscore');
```

or its better to pass it from main file:

```
//app.js
var _ = require('underscore');
require('./app_modules/module1.js')(_); // passing _ as argument
require('./app_modules/module2.js')(_); // passing _ as argument
require('./app_modules/module3.js')(_); // passing _ as argument
(..)
```

Does it make any difference?

Comment: use the one that keeps clutter out of your main file (require is cached anyway)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module is cached after it is loaded the first time, so you can require it in every file just fine. `require()` calls `Module._load`:

```
Module._load = function(request, parent, isMain) {
  // 1. Check Module._cache for the cached module. 
  // 2. Create a new Module instance if cache is empty.
  // 3. Save it to the cache.
  // 4. Call module.load() with your the given filename.
  //    This will call module.compile() after reading the file contents.
  // 5. If there was an error loading/parsing the file, 
  //    delete the bad module from the cache
  // 6. return module.exports
};
```

see: http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/

Comment: Here's the actual code in `node/lib/module.js`: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L273

Answer (score 0):

The first option is generally the best.

Since the require is cached, there is not performance improve choosing the second option. The advantage of using the first option is that it's easier to understand and that you won't need to make each module behave as a function with the Underscore library as a parameter.

However, you may want to be able to change easily the library you are using. If that's the case, the second option makes sense, because you'd just need to change the library in the main file. Anyway, I believe this is use case is not at all common, so probably you are fine using the first option.

Comment: You could also achieve changing libraries by creating a second file called `library.js` with the contents `module.exports = require('underscore')` and then just requiring `library.js` in each file as needed.

Comment: I had the same questions for long time and now i see that it's better to use connection of X library exactly where you use this - in all places. That way if you use any bundling system can distinct which libs used by given module. That's rather Frontend related (webpack, browserify bundling). As an advantage your IDE won't argue that some lib is not connected and bundling system can achieve (if there is support) modules lazy loading.